# Azure Application Insights profiler errors

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-application-insights-profiler

I have integrated Azure Application insights to my Azure app service(API app) and turned on profiler, snapshot also, but few exceptions are getting logged very frequently.

I have integrated Azure Application insights to my Azure app service(API app) and turned on profiler, snapshot also as shown in below picture.

[image: EnablingProfiler]

My App service plan is on B2. The below exceptions, traces are frequently getting logged in Application insights. Could you please help me to understand if there is any problem with the integration.

Exceptions

[image: Exceptions]
and

Traces

[image: Traces]

Comment: How you have configured ApplicationInsights in your app?

Comment: What is the framework of your App? Could you please share your `.csproj` and configuration file.

Comment: Do you have any other apps running the profiler within the same azure app service plan?It seems that multiple apps are running the profiler.

Comment: @Harshitha I have 10 other apps running the profiler within same app service plan. Framework of my app is .net 6. We are creating the app services and mapping to application insights through ARM template which will enable the profiler and snapshot aswell.

Comment: Try to stop profiling for few apps and check whether this app is running or not.

Comment: Even [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/azure-monitor/app-insights/profiler-troubleshooting#too-many-active-profiling-sessions) says the same, We can profile a maximum of 4 Apps at a time in a single app service plan.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlGME.png)

Comment: The only solution available is to change the App service plan of the web app.

Comment: Are you suggesting to move the Apps to different App service plans as it supports profile only for 4 apps in a single app service plan?

Comment: Yes..try to move this or any other old app currently  which you are not using.

Comment: If you want to profile...yes you need to move the app to other app service plan.

Comment: Any challenges in moving the app  to other service plan?

Comment: Noting except the budget. We have 11 micro service apps running on same app service plan now. For testing purpose we can move and test.

Comment: In that case as I have suggested, stop other apps for few mins and check the profiling for this App. You will come to know if that is the exact reason which is stopping.

Comment: Sure will check that and update. Thank you.

Comment: Do i need to turn off Snapshot as well?

Comment: Snapshot is something else , but disable that as well to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Harshitha Even after disabling the profiler we are getting the exceptions. Is that because of snapshot? if we disable we are not getting any issues. Is there any relation between profiler and snapshot?

Comment: Yes..I have checked few docs, there is a relation between the Profiler and Snapshot Debugger.

Comment: Snapshot displays the exception details which is logged by the profiler.

Comment: Ok, But we did not enable the profiler, still it is capturing the profiler logs. Do we need to disable both in our case compulsary?

Comment: Yes..disable both profiler and snapshot.May be you have packages related to profiler has been still running in backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have configured the Application Insights and enabled Profiler for a `.NET Core 6` Web App.

[image]

[image]

Iam able to see the profiler logs without any issues.

[image]

- Even you can see I have only the traces and Requests (not the exceptions).
  [image]

As per this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/azure-monitor/app-insights/profiler-troubleshooting#too-many-active-profiling-sessions), we can profile a maximum of only 4 Webapps within a same App Service Plan.

- And as you have mentioned,

> I have 10 other apps running the profiler within same app service plan

Which is not possible, that is the reason you are getting the exceptions.
Even the exception says to stop the Previous sessions.

As per the Doc, the solution available is to

> move some web apps to a different service plan.

Comment: I am not getting any issue after turning off both snapshot and profile. Turning off profile only didn't help.